# How to Get distinct value from one column in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

My Requirement is I need to take all distinct value from one column and to display
in Report Header section.

For eg.

```
Year
2008
2009
2010
2008
2009
```

It must print like `2008,2009,2010` in Report Header section.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a subreport, then select the distinct years and print them or write them in a shared variable to use them in your main report.

To select only the distinct values either

- use a command as a datasource `select distinct year from yourtable`
- check `Database | Select Distinct Records` in the menu for the subreport